# How to replace tag with different id in string?

Tags: javascript, string, emoji

I have a string. emoji-id can be different

`<tg-emoji emoji-id="5818665600624365278">⏺</tg-emoji>`

I want to leave only emoticons

`⏺`

Is it possible to do this using regular expressions in JS? How to do it?

Comment: If this is an element in the DOM, the correct approach is `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("tg-emoji")).forEach((element) => element.replaceChildren(element.textContent));`. You can then use [`normalize`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/normalize) to merge separate Text nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper function that I call stripHTML (or stripTags) that does exactly that.

```js
function stripHtml(html) {
  var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
  tmp.innerHTML = html;
  return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
var html = '<tg-emoji emoji-id="5818665600624365278">⏺</tg-emoji>';
console.log(stripHtml(html))
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be a two scenarios **:**

1. If It is a string, then you can achieve this by using `RegEx` with the help of [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

```js
const str = '<tg-emoji emoji-id="5818665600624365278">⏺</tg-emoji>';

const res = str.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '');

console.log(res);
```

2. If input is a HTML, then you can get the `innerText` or `textContent`

```js
const res = document.getElementsByTagName("tg-emoji")[0].innerText;

console.log(res);
```

```html
<tg-emoji emoji-id="5818665600624365278">⏺</tg-emoji>
```